# Debugging strategy for PHP-FPM

Tags: php-fpm

So I'm just setting up nginx and php5-fpm on my VPS, having moved over from Apache. I'm running Debian Squeeze, with the latest PHP from the dotdeb.org repo (that means PHP 5.4.13-1~dotdeb.1).

I am having trouble getting php5-fpm going. When run `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm start`, I don't get any confirmation, nor any error signals. Same for running `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop`. If I pass it the status arg (`sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm status`), it returns `php5-fpm is not running ... failed!`

Now I can't see any errors in any log, so I'm at a losss as to how to even start to debug the problem.

Has anyone experience similar problems, or knows what I should do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# /etc/init.d/php5-fpm check
[19-Apr-2013 19:29:26] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Try to use this :)

or

```
# /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm status
```

(replace 7.4 with your version)

Answer (score 1):

**Debian 9: nginx+PHP (2019)**

```
# php5-fpm -t
[08-Jan-2019 20:48:16] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf 
test is successful
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, but please do it by commenting on your choice.

Comment: This is perfect for doing a simple validation of a conf file, especially when php-fpm is containerized and running in the foreground. Thanks for posting!